# Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead

Tags: javascript, webpack

A am trying to build a webpack resolver and the `.plugin` method code below seems to be deprecated and I can't find the analogous method call using `.hooks`.

```
module.exports = class Resolver {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.plugin('module', function (init, callback) {
            console.log(init);
            return callback();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found it, this works:

```
module.exports = class Resolver {
    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.module.tapPromise('module', async (init) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(init));
            return init;
        });
    }
}
```